# How do I send numpy array with ROS services?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am writing a service in ROS and need to send 3D numpy arrays through this service. I know that for the messages there is numpy_msg, but haven't found anything similar for the services.
Thanks for the help! :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246282/how-do-i-send-numpy-array-with-ros-services?/) by [GPaolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28323/gpaolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if there is an existing serviec/message type that you can use out of box, but reshape the 3D array into a 1D array then simply use float64[] would probably work.

[Creating ROS srv/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)

---

Originally posted by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) with karma: 271 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two tips:

1. You can use any existing messages to create a service. More info on that can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv).
2. When you use numpy_msg, you're messages are actually going to be passed along as float32[] messages. The numpy_msg package just provides a nice way to serialize and deserialize float32[] messages directly into numpy arrays. More info on that [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy).

So you could have a service that, for example, takes a numpy array and int in the request, and responds with a new numpy array, that would look something like this:

```
int32 an_integer
float32[] input_array
---
float32[] output_array
```

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2